# Is there any added value in https over hidden service?

Tags: https, ssl

Is there any added value in using https with a hidden service, such as Facebook is doing?

Does the SSL provide any more security than regular http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it is, like these:

- Client SSL certificates for personalized accounting
- Enforcing of strong crypto : by the tor protocol specs a cipherset is negotiated, and can be not a stron one. But regardless of the transporting onion crypto - a strong 256-bit AES can be enforced during HTTPS handshake
- Server authenticity verification: if the Tor HS keys are hijacked, it **does not mean that the HTTPS keys are stolen too**. Even if they are on the same server.